# Warning in property initialization in class with primary constructor

Tags: c#, c#-12.0, primary-constructor

I noticed that a snippet like the below one, it marks the property initialization with a warning.

```
public sealed class C(int a)
{
    public int A { get; } = a;  //<--here

    public int Sum(int b)
    {
        return a + b;
    }
}
```

The warning says:

> warning CS9124: Parameter 'int a' is captured into the state of the
> enclosing type and its value is also used to initialize a field,
> property, or event.

However, if I omit any further `a` variable usage, the warning disappears.

```
public sealed class C(int a)
{
    public int A { get; } = a;

    public int Sum(int b)
    {
        return b;  //<-- no more 'a' used here
    }
}
```

Now, it is not very clear to me the reason of the warning, although I have a suspect. Is it because any `a` modification in the class will not change the `A` property, in this case?

Comment: [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/constructor-errors#primary-constructor-declaration) it says: "CS9124: *Parameter is captured into the state of the enclosing type and its value is also used to initialize a field, property, or event.* This warning indicates that the constructor parameter of a nested type is also captured by the enclosing type. The parameter is likely stored twice." Something you may want to avoid.

Comment: @Clemens that's exactly what's the SharpLab compiled source shows: there are two backing fields.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens because compiler will generate one backing field for `a` used in `Sum` and another backing field for auto-property `A`.

Note that `a` is mutable, while `A` is not hence you can do:

```cs
public void MutateA(int i) => a += i;
```

Which will affect `Sum` but will not affect `A`:

```
C c = new C(42);
c.MutateA(7);
Console.WriteLine(c.A); // Prints 42
Console.WriteLine(c.Sum(0)); // Prints 49

public sealed class C(int a)
{
    public int A { get; } = a;  //<--here

    public int Sum(int b)
    {
        return a + b;
    }

    public void MutateA(int i) => a += i;
}
```

The workaround/fix would be to use `A` instead of `a` in the `Sum`:

```cs
public int Sum(int b) =>  A + b;
```

See also:

- [Resolve errors and warnings in constructor declarations: Primary constructor declaration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/constructor-errors#primary-constructor-declaration)

Comment: okay, my suspect was correct. Not very helpful the warning message, though.

Comment: yeah...that's also the most criticized fault of the primary constructors. A `readonly` prefix would be helpful.

Comment: @MarioVernari _"A readonly prefix would be helpful."_ - yes, AFAIK language team is considering it for the next release. But arguably it should have been the default behaviour.